# Check it is empty or not in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter.I have created one function in model.The function is like this :

```
function pr($id)
    {
        //$query5 = $this->db->query("select max(to_date) as last_date from agent_print_details where agent_id = ".$id);
        //$result5 = $query5->result();

        $this->db->select('max(to_date) as last_date');
        $this->db->from('agent_print_details');
        $this->db->where('agent_id',$id);

        $result = $this->db->get();

        if($result->num_rows()>0)

        return $result->result();

        else

        return "empty";

    }
```

my controller is :

```
$pr_detail = $this->cashier1_model->pr($role['id']);

if($pr_detail != 0)
{
    echo "nisarg";
}
else
{
    echo "123";
}
```

when I print pr_detail then it will display output like this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [last_date] => ) )
```

it will give blank data so it has to print **123** but it is display **nisarg**.

So What should i have to do to print **123**?

Comment: see what's inside  $result after $result = $this->db->get(); use print_r($result ); and see if it is really > 0, my guess is that the model is returning the string "empty" which will result  as a TRUE value inside the if($pr_detail), so it will always echo "nisarg", check the model !

Answer (score 5):

If result not found just return `FALSE` in model file. Also use CI `select_max` to get max value

**MODEL**

```
$this->db->select_max('to_date','last_date');
$this->db->from('agent_print_details');
$this->db->where('agent_id', $id);
$result = $this->db->get();
if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $result->result();
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$pr_detail = $this->cashier1_model->pr($role['id']);

if($pr_detail)
{
    echo "nisarg";
}
else
{
    echo "123";
}
```

Comment: It show nisarg because your query return data . If your query does'n result data then it goes into else condition

Comment: you try with my code with some ids which is not present in your database and check the result

Comment: yeah.. but in my database there is no record related to that id

Comment: i want to use **as** with **select_max**. so how can i use?

Comment: it gives an error like this : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS last_date) AS to_date AS last_date FROM (`agent_print_details`) WHERE `agent_' at line 1

Comment: Ahh my mistake i change my code you can create alias like this `$this->db->select_max('to_date','last_date');`

Answer (score 1):

you could use count function, also, do you have defined a table name in get function?

```
...
$result = $this->db->get('agent_print_details');
//if($result->num_rows() > 0)
if(count($result) > 0)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use $result->num_rows() > 0 you CANT use $result->result(). If u want to return these results, you need to check if its not empty first, and then query again to get results.

```
$this->db->select_max('to_date','last_date');
$this->db->from('agent_print_details');
$this->db->where('agent_id', $id);
$result = $this->db->get();
if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {

   $this->db->select_max('to_date','last_date');
   $this->db->from('agent_print_details');
   $this->db->where('agent_id', $id);
   $result = $this->db->get();

   return $result->result();

} else {

    return FALSE;

}
```